# How to load Resx Files under App_LocalResources to Iterate through it

Tags: asp.net, webforms, resources, resx

I need the ResX file for the current page which is saved under "App_LocalResources".

I need to iterate through it.

The Method "GetLocalResourceObject" only allows access to one key at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Since a `resx` file is nothing more than a xml file, you can loop all the elements with `XElement`

```
string resxFile = Server.MapPath("/App_LocalResources/Default.aspx.resx");

foreach (XElement element in XElement.Load(resxFile).Elements("data"))
{
    string currentItem = string.Format("Key: {0}  Value: {1}", element.Attribute("name").Value, element.Element("value").Value);
}
```

Another option is with the `ResXResourceReader`. However you do need to add `System.Windows.Forms` as a reference to the project.

```
using System.Resources;

//define the filename and path for the resx file
string resxFile = Server.MapPath("/App_LocalResources/Default.aspx.resx");

//load the file into the reader
using (ResXResourceReader reader = new ResXResourceReader(resxFile))
{
    //loop all the entries
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in reader)
    {
        string currentItem = string.Format("Key: {0}  Value: {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }
}
```